# Animate SVG line between custom input price range

Tags: html, css, reactjs, svg

I'm building a price range slider with 2 inputs from min price to max price and a SVG line that would animate left/right inside the slider thumbs.

I'm struggling to find the math equation for that functionality because the left SVG x1 value needs to be 0 rather than the min input value if that makes sense.

I left a codeSandBox so you guys can have a look and see exactly what I'm trying to achieve here.

https://codesandbox.io/s/practical-bush-qq7dl?file=/src/App.js

```
import React, { useState } from "react";

export default function App() {
  const [minRange, setMinRange] = useState("");
  const [maxRange, setMaxRange] = useState("");
  const [staticRange, setStaticRange] = useState({
    min: 20,
    max: 112
  });
  const rangeSplit = staticRange.min + staticRange.max / 2;

  const handleChange = (input, e) => {
    const value = e.target.value;
    input === "min" ? setMinRange(value) : setMaxRange(value);
  };

  return (
    <div className="slider">
      <div className="slider__inputs">
        <input
          min={staticRange.min}
          max={rangeSplit}
          type="range"
          value={minRange}
          onChange={(e) => handleChange("min", e)}
        />
        <input
          min={rangeSplit}
          max={staticRange.max}
          type="range"
          value={maxRange}
          onChange={(e) => handleChange("max", e)}
        />

        <svg width="100%" height="4">
          <line
            x1={minRange}
            y1="0"
            x2={maxRange}
            y2="0"
            stroke="#444"
            stroke-width="12"
          ></line>
        </svg>
      </div>
      <div className="slider__range">
        <span>{`£${minRange}`}</span>
        <span>{`£${maxRange}`}</span>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Effect desired:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

your svg line is defined in terms of %, therefore you need to convert your x1, x2 values into percentages as kca indicated above.

therefore all you need to do is to compute the total range as the staticRange.max - staticRange.min.

```
const totalRange=(staticRange.max - staticRange.min);
```

in addition you will need to set the range split to a position between the static min, and max, so if you min is 20, and the max is 112, the rangeSplit needs to be 66, (66 is 46 more than 20, and 46 less than 112).

```
const rangeSplit = staticRange.min+(totalRange / 2);
```

Then, when defining your x1 and x2 points, take the difference between the slider position and the staticRange.min value and covert to %.

```
x1={(100 * ((minRange-staticRange.min)/totalRange)) + "%"}

x2={(100 * ((maxRange-staticRange.min)/totalRange)) + "%"}
```

Thus as you can see, when minRange == staticRange.min, the value is 0% and when maxRange == staticRange.max, the value is totalRange/totalRange which is equal to 100%.

Comment: Appreciate your time, works like a charm.

Answer (score 1):

The Math is

> x% = 100% * value / range

You have to do this calculation for both, start and end of the line.

#### Explaination

See [Cross-multiplication](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-multiplication).

`x% / value = 100% / (112-20)`, when multiplied by `value` means `x% = 100% / (112-20) * value`.

It is sometimes better to multiply before dividing, therefore I like to just always do it:
`x% = 100% * value / (112-20)`

#### Example

```
const usePercent = (min, max, value)=>{
  const [ valuePct, setValuePct ] = useState(0);

  useEffect(()=>{
    const valueNum      = (value && value > min) ? value : min; // should never be less than min
    const rangeSize     = max - min;       // e.g. 112 - 20 = 92
    const relativeValue = valueNum - min;  // e.g. change value 20...112 --> 0...91
    const percent       = 100 * relativeValue / rangeSize  // 100% / 92 === x% / relativeValue

    setValuePct( percent );

  }, [ min, max, value ]);

  return valuePct;
};

const Line = (props)=>{
  const { minValue, maxValue, minOffset, maxOffset } = props;
  const minPercent = usePercent( minOffset, maxOffset, minValue );
  const maxPercent = usePercent( minOffset, maxOffset, maxValue );

  return (<svg width="100%" height="40">
    <line
        x1={ minPercent + '%' }
        y1="0"
        x2={ maxPercent + '%' }
        y2="0"
        stroke="#444"
        strokeWidth="12"
    />
  </svg>);
};

export default function App() {
...
  return (
...
        <Line
            minValue={ minRange }
            maxValue={ maxRange }
            minOffset={ 20 }
            maxOffset={ 112 }
        />
...
  );
};
```

Comment: thanks for taking the time in answering, I was missing that part, I guess I'm not good at math :)